# Java 1.9 Module: Different output for same class using java while overwriting java.net.InetAddress

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

- Added SOP in `getAllByName()` and `isLoopbackAddress()` method in `java.net.InetAddress`. Compiled `InetAddress.java` using below command

  ```
  javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatch src/java/net/InetAddress.java
  ```
- While Executing below code `getAllByName("localhost")` prints SOP. But other two doesn't.

  ```
  java --patch-module java.base=mypatch CustomInetAddCall.. 

  InetAddress addr[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("localhost"); // prints SOP.
  System.out.println([0].isLoopbackAddress()); // Doesn't
  System.out.println(addr[0].getHostAddress()); // Doesn't
  ```

Comment: This question is not clear. What does the forked/hacked version of java.net.InetAddress do?

Comment: @AlanBateman I would just add(to what I understood) SOP as `System.out.println` for debugging purpose. Other than that @Gopi could explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that could possibly be that

- `getAllByName` is an API defined within the `InetAddress` class while
- `isLoopbackAddress` and `getHostAddress` both have there *overridden implementation being in use*, instead of the one from `InetAddress.java` class which you have patched.

In order to add those debugging steps to the above methods, you would probably have to patch the [`Inet4Address`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) and [`Inet6Address`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) classes with your custom method implementation that overrides the `InetAddress` class implementation.